# Flip face in obj file

Tags: unity-game-engine, .obj

I'm dynamically creating a 3D model and writing an .obj file. I'm having a problem with flipping the visible side of faces.

I've made a simple example:

```
v  0.0  0.0  0.0
v  0.0  1.0  0.0
v  1.0  0.0  0.0
v  1.0  1.0  0.0

vn  0.0  0.0 -1.0

f  1//1  4//1  3//1
f  1//1  2//1  4//1
```

[image]

The above is a square divided into two triangles. The `vn` line is the face normal (the vector that is perpendicular to the face). I've read online that to flip the face, you can negate the normal vector. However if I multiply the normal vector by -1 and try the following...

```
v  0.0  0.0  0.0
v  0.0  1.0  0.0
v  1.0  0.0  0.0
v  1.0  1.0  0.0

vn  0.0  0.0 1.0

f  1//1  4//1  3//1
f  1//1  2//1  4//1
```

[image]

It doesn't actually flip the visible side of the face when I import it into Unity. The lighting changes a little bit, but the same side is still visible and the other side is still invisible.

When I orbit to the opposite side:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal only influences the lighting effect. To flip a face, you need to inverse the index order of the triangle like below.

```
f  3//1  4//1  1//1
f  4//1  2//1  1//1
```